# react native scrollview horizontal swipe left or right on tap

Tags: react-native, scrollview, gesture

I am showing pictures gallery in full screen mode. I am using scrollview in horizontal for scrolling the pictures. Right now I can scroll the pictures by swiping left or right and I using the `pagingEnabled` enabled props.

But I want to add more gesture, where when user tap on left or right ( a distance from the edge) , it will automatically mapping the swapping gesture.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a `ref` to the `<ScrollView>` then to `scrollToEnd()` or use `scrollTo` methods - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrollto

To calculate page number, you would use `onLayout` to calculate sizes of your pages. If it's the width of the device then that's easy, just use `Dimensions.get('window').width` then feed that to the `x` in `scrollTo`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but can you elaborate more? Like how can I track the tap gesture on the edge?

Comment: @dev-jim To check for tap on edge you would have to put an invisible element there to test for taps.

Comment: I got it figured out. Anyway thanks for your help. You answer give me the inspiration. So I gonna accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks @dev-jim may you please share how you did it. Was it with invisible element? And `scrollTo` method?

Answer (score 2):

I assume your scroll view looks like this with **pagingEnabled** and **horizontal** props.

```
<ScrollView
   horizontal={true}
   pagingEnabled={true}
   onMomentumScrollEnd={event => {
      this.setState({xOffset: event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x })
   }}>
      // Content 
</ScrollView>
```

The position can be calculated with :

`this.state.xOffset/ DeviceSize.width`

onMomentumScrollEnd is called each time you scroll an item in the ScrollView

*(the content must be full width in this case)*