# How to create a Horizontal Recycle View in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a list of questions that I have to get from an API, and I want to render each question one at a time so when I press one of the three buttons (yes, no, maybe) the next question renders.

Ex. 1st question pops up -> You answer it -> 2nd question comes -> You answer it -> Process repeats until the last question.

[Recycle View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPsmr.gif)

This is how I want it to kinda look, I tried using the react-native-recycler-view-list but it didn't work.

How do I make this kind of list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react native scrollview horizontal swipe left or right on tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429464/react-native-scrollview-horizontal-swipe-left-or-right-on-tap)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have an optimised list view in react native just like recycler view of android, you can make use of FlatList. But, you can have optimisation either horizontally or vertically but not both ways at a time. You can simply import FlatList from react-native in your component.
You can go through this link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html to know more about FlatList